# How to make that all works together.Intent, onClickListener, Several classes, Show another activity

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make my application show another activity using 3 classes:

1. `MainActivity` - main screen
2. `ActivityOne` - second screen
3. `ButtonListener` - activity for `onClickListener`

My code for `ActivityMain`:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
        button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    }
}
```

My code for `ActivityOne`:

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_one);
    }
}
```

My code for `ButtonListener`:

```
public class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ButtonListener() {}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityOne.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error? Please turn to the help center and read about how to ask here.

Comment: First parameter in `new Intent()` should be an instance of `Context` (e.g. `MainActivity.this`) and not a `Class` instance. If you have access to instance of `MainActivity` use that. If not, get it somehow (by passing as an constructor argument).

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Comment: The thing is, if i declare onClickListener in MainActivity and inside the onCLick method i have Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls) and i call it with startActivity everything Works. I would like to now how  to make it work if  i want to make another class witch gona take care about my onClickListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust `ButtonListener` to maintain reference to `MainActivity`:

```
    public class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        MainActivity activity;

        public ButtonListener(MainActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;   
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivityOne.class);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Then in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`, create instance of `ButtonListener` this way:

```
ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks but The line startActivity(intent); gives an error "Cannot resolve method startActivity". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because that method is not in OnClickListener. But it is accessible via Activity. See the edit.

Comment: Perfect It Works! Thank you verry much!

Comment: Glad to have helped. But I suppose you understand why these errors were occurring and why they don't appear now. Because these are very commonly occurring errors and can be easily fixed.

Comment: I suppose that first parameter in new Intent() didnt know from were to get it, for that i had to make an instance of MainActivity, and later use it in first parameter and to call a method startActivity(). Is that right? Correct me please if im wrong, because for me it is important to understand. I just started with programing. Im beginer )

Comment: Balkrishna Rawool. I have another question. How can i add one or more Intent to same ButtonListener class. Is there a way how to add to onClick method? Thanks